# Web page scraping gems/tools available in Ruby

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, lxml, scrape

I'm trying to scrape web pages in a Ruby script that I'm working on.  The purpose of the project is to show which ETFs and stock mutual funds are most compatible with the value investing philosophy.

Some examples of pages I'd like to scrape are:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=SPY+Profile
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hl?s=SPY+Holdings
http://www.marketwatch.com/tools/mutual-fund/list/V
```

What web scraping tools do you recommend for Ruby, and why?  Keep in mind that there are thousands of stock funds out there, so any tool I use has to be reasonably quick.

I am new to Ruby, but I have experience using lxml to scrape web pages in Python (https://github.com/jhsu802701/dopplervalueinvesting/blob/master/screen.py).  Once the pages on 5000+ stocks are downloaded, lxml can scrape them all in just a few minutes.  (I remember trying BeautifulSoup but rejecting it because it was too slow.)

Comment: Yahoo finance actually has many APIs available, you should be using one of those.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are so many `scraping gems` available in `Ruby` like [Hpricot](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot), [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) and so many. I recommend `Nokogiri` to scrape `static web pages`. If you are scraping `dynamic web pages` (means which involves button click, submit form etc..). I recommend [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) which internally uses `Nokogiri`.

Comment: Hpricot is no longer has a maintainer. I would recommend using Nokogiri :)

Answer (score 1):

I see a list of HTML parsing solutions at https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing.html .  I'm going with Nokogiri because it's the only one that's still active.